# Why doesn't my code work for cells I'm adding after the code was written?

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked in previous posts about a macro to match all cells with the same text to the color of a single cell. That way I can just color in the parent cell, run the macro, and it will find all child cells with the same text and color them in for me. With help of some of you, I have figured that out.

Fast forward about a month, I realized that in my workbook I had forgotten an entry of a child cell and added it to all sheets in the workbook. The problem now is that the macro won't color that new child cell in. My code can be seen below, I purposefully made `.Range("C1:K75")`, big enough to account for any new child cells so I don't think that is the issue. Another child cell with the same text existed in the workbook in another place already, and I have copy pasted the text from the parent cell and original child cell to make sure the text matched exactly. The original child cell will get colored but, but the new child cell still will not. I have googled around about vba code accounting new cells but can't seem to find anything. No error codes pop up or anything, it just won't color in that cell as if it is not even there. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub MatchAll()

'This will match the color of documents in the Job Description Reqs. to the color
'of the documents in the documents list, color in document on the list on the left side,
'run the macro, and it should make all the same documents in the sheet the same color

    Dim c As Range, r As Range, i As Long
    Dim sDocument As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 8 To 200                         'Runs the macro for every cell
            Set r = .Range("A" & i)              'from A8:A200
            sDocument = CStr(r.Value)            'name of document you are looking for is now equal to name in document list
            If Not sDocument = vbNullString Then                 'if the cell in the document list is not blank then
                With .Range("C1:K75")                            'within the range of the Job Description Reqs.
                    Set c = .Find(sDocument, LookIn:=xlValues)   'look for the name of document stated in document list
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then                                    'if a document within the range of Job Description Reqs. is found
                        If Not c.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color Then         'and the documents in both the list and Job Description Reqs. are not the same color
                            Do
                                c.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color             'make the color of the Job Description Req. Document = the color of the list document
                                Set c = .FindNext(c)                            'find the next document listed in the Job Description Reqs,
                            Loop While Not c.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color  'Repeat until all documents of that name are the same color
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next i                                   'Move onto next document in document list and repeat
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure but your problem might be `Loop While Not c.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color`. Could you be ending the loop prematurely if you find a cell which matches colour - could there be other which don't match but you will then miss?

Answer (score 0):

Keep looping till the Find returns to the first found cell. You can set the color regardless of its existing color.

```vb
Sub MatchAll()

'This will match the color of documents in the Job Description Reqs. to the color
'of the documents in the documents list, color in document on the list on the left side,
'run the macro, and it should make all the same documents in the sheet the same color

    Dim c As Range, r As Range, i As Long
    Dim sDocument As String, sFirst As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 8 To 200                         'Runs the macro for every cell
            Set r = .Range("A" & i)              'from A8:A200
            sDocument = CStr(r.Value)            'name of document you are looking for is now equal to name in document list
            If Not sDocument = vbNullString Then                 'if the cell in the document list is not blank then
                With .Range("C1:K75")                            'within the range of the Job Description Reqs.
                    Set c = .Find(sDocument, LookIn:=xlValues)   'look for the name of document stated in document list
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then     'if a document within the range of Job Description Reqs. is found
                        sFirst = c.Address       'and the documents in both the list and Job Description Reqs
                        Do
                            c.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color             'make the color of the Job Description Req. Document = the color of the list document
                            Set c = .FindNext(c)                            'find the next document listed in the Job Description Reqs,
                        Loop While Not c.Address = sFirst  'Repeat until all documents of that name are the same color
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next i                                   'Move onto next document in document list and repeat
    End With
End Sub
```